# using awk to unzip files in directory

Tags: sed, awk, grep

I have some zip files in directory when I need to unzip each in specific dir 
I used

```
ls | awk '{ print "unzip " $1 " -d " $1} '
unzip p21286665_121020_Linux-x86-64.zip -d p21286665_121020_Linux-x86-64.zip
unzip p21841318_121020_Linux-x86-64.zip -d p21841318_121020_Linux-x86-64.zip
unzip p22098146_121020_Linux-x86-64.zip -d p22098146_121020_Linux-x86-64.zip
```

But I need something like this.

```
unzip p21286665_121020_Linux-x86-64.zip -d p21286665
unzip p21841318_121020_Linux-x86-64.zip -d p21841318
unzip p22098146_121020_Linux-x86-64.zip -d p22098146
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could also use the -F argument to split the line on underscore and thus end up with something like this:

```
ls | awk -F_ '{print "unzip " $0 " -d " $1; }
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
ls | awk '{ print "unzip " $1 " -d " substr($1,1,index($1,"_")-1) } '
```

or in sed

```
ls | sed -e "s/\([^_]*\)_.*$/unzip & -d \1/"
```

where

- `[^_]*` is  a non _ string
- `\(` .. `\)` catpure as `\1`
- `&` is whole pattern